# Array of objects length

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am reading a file which have the following data. And i am assigning it to `arr`.

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "One": {
                "One one": [
                    "Hello"
                ]
            }
        },
        "name": "1898061c-bd49-4e35-bfb6-6514fbe9c5c4"
    }
]
```

When i access the first element like `console.log(arr.length)` **it gives me 1** in **chrome console (manually declaring array there).** which is fine.

**But when i console log to actual terminal it gives me 209.**

Comment: How are you logging to the terminal?

Comment: Note that `JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4).length; // => 209`

Comment: @SumeetKumar The actual array is above. It have one object.

Comment: @Camilo Yes i am logging to the terminal

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the "arr" object is an array and not a string.

The array has length one, the stringified JSON of the array has length 209:

```
JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4).length; // => 209
```

Comment: But how will i iterate it ? I need to insert the data to DB.

Comment: @Gammer Not enough context. You wrote you have an array, but apparently you have a JSON encoded string. Fix your question!

Comment: I have updated my question, But how can i convert that to actual array ?

Comment: @Gammer You just declared your example array a string, which it clearly isn't! You are confused about what kind of data you've got! Do you understand the difference between a string and an array (of whatever)? Now your comment says "string" but your code still has an array of objects.

Comment: I have updated the question .

Comment: @Gammer Please read the COMMENT! Your latest edit still does not change anything. You are clueless about what a string is vs. what an array is and which of the two you got. The string CONTAINS a (JSON encoded) array - it still is a string! Unless you decode it.

Comment: @Gammer try logging `typeof(arr)` from the terminal, as you say; you'll probably get "string", which means your "arr" is not an array but a string.

Comment: @Mörre I understand now that i have a string not array, The file i am reading and assigning its content to a variable is string not array, Now what can possibly be done with that ?

Comment: @Gammer `arr = JSON.parse(arr);`